# Rotating NSView around center

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsanimation, nsanimationcontext

I'm trying to animate the rotation of an NSView around its center, but it keeps shifting side to side during rotation. What is causing this?

```
-(void)startRefreshAnimation {

    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.0];
    [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
    [NSAnimationContext currentContext].completionHandler = ^{ [self startRefreshAnimation]; };
    [[view animator] setFrameCenterRotation:previousRotation - 90.0];
    previousRotation += -90.0;
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

}
```

Shift up during rotation:

[image]

Shift down during rotation:

[image]

Comment: Did you try logging your frame? Could it have invisible portions that modify the center location unexpectedly?

Comment: @BenMosher The background color is set to red. That's the entire view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

If the application has altered the layer’s anchorPoint property, the behavior is undefined. Sending this message to a view that is not managing a Core Animation layer causes an exception.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html

Is your view managing a CALayer with an unmodified anchor point?

**EDIT**

I setup similar code at got the exact same results. No adjust of origin or anchor point could resolve this problem. My theory is that this particular method contains bugs (does for autolayout), or works in a way which we don't anticipate. I achieved the correct effect using `CABasicAnimation`.

```
/* setup */

....
     _view.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);
     _view.layer.position = ...

    [self startRefreshAnimation];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self startRefreshAnimation];
}

-(void)startRefreshAnimation {

    CABasicAnimation *anim2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    anim2.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    anim2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:previousRotation * (M_PI / 180.0f)];
    anim2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(previousRotation + 90.0f) * (M_PI / 180.0f)];
    previousRotation = previousRotation + 90.0f;
    anim2.duration = 1.0f;
    anim2.delegate = self;
    [_view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"transform"];
}
```

Comment: I'm creating and managing a `CALayer` on my view (to set the background color to purple), but I'm not modifying the anchor point. See my edit to view the code affecting the `CALayer.`

Comment: @JackHumphries Im curious, doesnt the second layer overwrite the first makeBackingLayer?

Comment: I didn't notice. I just copied and pasted the code from online without interpreting it.

Comment: When I call `setFrameCenterRotation` on `view` instead of `[view animator]`, it works, but the rotation is instant. There is no animation.

Comment: @JackHumphries hmm - I am setting up a test on my comp ill let you know

Comment: @JackHumphries alright I have mine working just like yours and I think I know the problem. It rotates around the corner - but that corner position changes every rotation cycle. This makes it look like it's close even though it's way off.

Comment: This works better, though it rotates by the bottom left corner, instead of around the center. Do you know how to fix this? I did set the anchor point to (0.5f, 0.5f).

Comment: @JackHumphries hmm I set the frame before I set the anchorPoint and position, I wonder if that has something to do with it...

Comment: Justin's answer works because it adjusts the layer's transform. Apple does strange things with the anchorPoint when using `setFrameCenterRotation`, even if you set the anchorPoint. This was my experience and Isaac Chen provides an excellent write-up: https://isaacxen.github.io/2017/12/21/rotating-a-view-is-not-easy/

Answer (score 2):

here is the dummy project and the answer that I found. (For Cocoa Applicaiton)

[Rotate NSImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985344/nsimageview-is-hoping-when-from-the-location-when-trying-to-rotate-how-to-stop)

[github project (download)](https://github.com/bansalvks/Mac-Dummies.git)